# XCTestCase for CloudKit

Tags: unit-testing, cloudkit, xctest

Is is any way to test CloudKit inside XCTestCase? As far as I know you can't connect to CloudKit server without your personal certificate, I'm developing public open-source CloudKit framework and I can't include personal entitlements/certificates there.

What's the best way to test CloudKit in such situations?

Comment: Did you found out how ?